# Is there any difference between subsetting the data and limiting data on axis's ?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get different plots when I use a subset of data while creating a plot or use limit on both x and y axis. Here I'm limiting data to omit the top 1% of values.

Subset the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
ggplot(data = subset(diamonds, price <= quantile(price, 0.99),
    carat <= quantile(carat, 0.99)), aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
 geom_jitter(alpha = 1/20)
```

[image]
Limits on both axis:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  scale_x_continuous(lim = c(0, quantile(diamonds$carat, 0.99))) +
  scale_y_continuous(lim = c(0, quantile(diamonds$price, 0.99))) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 1/20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the first plot should be:

```
ggplot(data = subset(diamonds, price <= quantile(price, 0.99) &
    carat <= quantile(carat, 0.99)), aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
 geom_jitter(alpha = 1/20)
```

Note the condition inside `subset`:

```
price <= quantile(price, 0.99) & carat <= quantile(carat, 0.99)
```

After this correction, the two plots are the same.

[image]

Comment: So literally, there is no difference?

Comment: @Srinam Yes, There are no differences, in my opinion.